# How to add new Rows to TableView in JavaFX, based on a sorted filtered List?

Tags: list, javafx, tableview, javafx-2

In my FXMLTableViewController.java I have added a Search feature which uses the Sorted Filtered List to display the search Results (filter results) in the same TableView. This code was taken from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8str55IrTAhUEto8KHSjuBhYQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.makery.ch%2Fblog%2Fjavafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering%2F&usg=AFQjCNF5inIbYjvc7sQrLx331PsPGM_r5A&sig2=YP5U4gIk64ZGtdF6B9EFbA) this is what I have implemented in my Project. But it throws exception when I do the usual `data2.add(new Entity(""));`

```
public class FXMLTableViewController {

@FXML
private TableView<Entity> tableView;

@FXML
private JFXTextField searchBox;

@FXML
public void initialize() throws IOException, ParseException {
 tableView.setItems(data2); //data2 is a observable list returned my another function, it is not related here.
    FilteredList<Entity> filteredData = new FilteredList<>   (data2, p -> true);
       searchBox.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,    newValue) -> {
           filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
              if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            return Person.getPsfName_add().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)
        });
    });
    SortedList<Entity> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
    tableView.setItems(sortedData);
    sortedData.add(new Entity("")); //error line 
    tableView.refresh();

}
```

}

Now whenever I try to add a new Entity object I get the Error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

This I guess is due to the fact that SortedLists are unmodifiable? How do I solve this? I want to add new Rows at various points in my Project but I also want the Search/Filter Facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted (and filtered) lists are unmodifiable. You should modify the *underlying* list (`data2`), and the sorted/filtered list will update automatically (it is observing the underlying `ObservableList`).

The code you need looks like:

```
public class FXMLTableViewController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Entity> tableView;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField searchBox;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException, ParseException {

        FilteredList<Entity> filteredData = new FilteredList<>   (data2, p -> true);
        searchBox.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,    newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }

                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                return Person.getPsfName_add().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)
            });
        });
        SortedList<Entity> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
        tableView.setItems(sortedData);

        data2.add(new Entity("")); //error line 

    }

}
```

Note for clarity I removed the first call to `tableView.setItems(...)` as you are only setting `items` to something else immediately afterwards. Also note that `tableView.refresh()` is redundant (the table is also observing the `ObservableList` that makes up its items).

Comment: Okay, another question, At certain points in my code I do a `AddRowsPopup.setTableList((tableView.getItems());` call to set this list to another list so that I can use it in another controller class. and in such cases the `public static ObservableLIst<Entity> data; setTableList(ObservableList<Entity> data3){ data=data3;}` is called and then this `data` variable is used to add rows from different controller class eg- `data.add(new Entity(""))`, just as one would use the previous data2 variable. and this again throws the previous `Unsupported Exception`  so again back to square one :(

Comment: It's basically the same question, isn't it? Use the underlying data in the model and share that list with whichever controllers need access to it, etc. Wrap the underlying list in a filtered and/or sorted list to display it in a table, if you want the table to display it in a filtered and/or sorted way. If you want to share the filtering/sorting among controllers, make the predicate/comparator part of the model and share those.

Comment: okay! i just fixed this!! all i needed to do was `setTableList(data2)` is this the right way to do it anyways?

Comment: Yes, basically, stop using `table.getItems()`.