# Add empty row in a sorted table

Tags: java, javafx

I have a table with two buttons (Search, Add). Here search button populates sorted data(also filtered) in the table. Now I am trying to add empty rows at the bottom of the table. It works fine when my table is empty but when there is data it is showing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` exception.I guess it is due to the fact that SortedLists are unmodifiable. How do I solve this? I want to add new Rows at top of the table but I also want the Search/Filter Facility. Here I trying to get my search result

```
private ObservableList<ModelBrFloor> getInfo(ModelBrBuilding building) {
            ObservableList list=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            List<ModelBrFloor> flr= implementation.getFloor(building);
            flr.stream().forEach(list:: add);
                FilteredList <ModelBrFloor> filteredData= new FilteredList<>(list,p->true);
                txtFloorName.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{
                    filteredData.setPredicate(BCode->{
                    if(newValue== null||newValue.isEmpty())
                        return true;
                    String lowerCasefilter=newValue.toLowerCase();
                    if(BCode.getFloorName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasefilter))
                        return true;
                    return false;
                    });

                });
                txtFloorShort.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{
                filteredData.setPredicate(BCode->{
                    if(newValue== null || newValue.isEmpty())
                        return true;
                    String lowerCasefilter= newValue.toLowerCase();
                    if(BCode.getFloorCode().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasefilter))
                        return true;
                    return false;
                });

                });


                SortedList sortedData = new SortedList(filteredData);
                sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableFloor.comparatorProperty());

        return sortedData;

        }
```

And here I am trying to add an empty row

```
@FXML
        private void addFloor() {

            tableFloor.getItems().add(0,new ModelBrFloor());// Error line

        }
```

N.B I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207183/how-to-add-new-rows-to-tableview-in-javafx-based-on-a-sorted-filtered-list) but it is not clear to me.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the first method and the AddFloor method. And also where is this UnsupportedOperationException thrown.
BTW, please change your AddFloor method to start with lower case.

Comment: you have to add it to the source list and make sure an "empty" item is sorted to the top

Comment: I have modified now. In the first method, I am showing how I filtered my table. Basically, the problem is in the `addFloor()`. And it is because of my filtered table.

Comment: the question you linked is an exact duplicate and its answer demonstrates exactly what you have to do.. so what is not clear?

Comment: Can you kindly give an example @kleopatra

Answer (score 3):

You're not allowed to modify a `SortedList`/`FilteredList`, since they are just a view of another list. You need to modify the original list:

```
private ObservableList<ModelBrFloor> data;

private ObservableList<ModelBrFloor> getInfo(ModelBrBuilding building) {
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(implementation.getFloor(building));

    FilteredList<ModelBrFloor> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(list);
    txtFloorName.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
        if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
            filteredData.setPredicate(null);
        } else {
            final String lowerCasefilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            filteredData.setPredicate(BCode -> {
                // keep empty and matching rows
                return isEmptyRow(BCode) || BCode.getFloorName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasefilter);
            });
        }

    });
    txtFloorShort.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
            filteredData.setPredicate(null);
        } else {
            final String lowerCasefilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            filteredData.setPredicate(BCode -> {
                return isEmptyRow(BCode) || BCode.getFloorCode().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasefilter);
            });

    });

    SortedList<ModelBrFloor> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
            final Comparator<ModelBrFloor> comparator = tableFloor.getComparator();
            return comparator == null ? null : (a, b) -> {
                // sort empty rows to the top, then use comparator
                if (isEmptyRow(a)) {
                    return isEmptyRow(b) ? 0 : -1;
                } else {
                    return isEmptyRow(b) ? 1 : comparator.compare(a, b);
                }
            };
        },
        tableFloor.comparatorProperty()));

    return sortedData;
}

@FXML
private void addFloor() {
    data.add(0, new ModelBrFloor());
}
```

`isEmptyRow` is a method checking, if a `ModelBrFloor` is empty.

Comment: what is `a,b` in this line `return comparator == null ? null : (a, b) -> ` Here I am getting error

Comment: @AritraPaul those are the parameters of the lambda expression for a `Comparator<ModelBrFloor>` and I overlooked that you didn't specify the type parameter for `SortedList`, which prevents the java compiler from determining the appropriate type parameters...

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. But I am getting an error in the `(a,b)` .